# Is there a simple MHT (Merkel Hash Tree) in-place algorithm?

Tags: rust, golang

I want to write a low memory usage algorithm to calculate MHT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see there is an implementation in Rust: [merkletree](https://docs.rs/merkletree/latest/merkletree/).
Also in the substrate repository there are some custom implementations you can take a look for inspirations: [Merkle Mountain Ranges](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/master/substrate/client/merkle-mountain-range) and a custom [Binary Merkle Tree](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/master/substrate/utils/binary-merkle-tree), that implements a simple binary Merkle Tree utilities required for inter-op with Ethereum bridge & Solidity contract.

Comment: Thank you so much